# Remove an uploaded header image

Tags: custom-header, header-image

I'm developing a theme which supports a header image, when you've uploaded a few header images you can select to show them randomly as header image. When you want to remove one header image you can do that in the Media Library, but isn't there an easier way to remove them?

Let's assume there are about 200 images in the Media Library and somewhere between them is a header image which you'd want to remove, how would you remove it?

I believe there should be an easy way to remove a specific header image in the "Header" screen, but I can't seem to find this option (most probably because it doesn't exist)?

**EDIT**

[image: Part of the WordPress custom header screen]

Currently there are 4 header images uploaded, these are shown randomly. Let's say I want to remove one header image so only 3 are shown.

Is there are an other way rather than going to the Media Library looking between all the files for that one header image (really annoying) and then deleting it, to delete one single header image?

Answer (score 1):

Well uploading image and using it as header image are two different things. Wordpress uploads image using media uploader and all images are stored in media library. Header image setting page just maps that which images should be used as header image. So to remove header image , you just have to remove its mapping. Though if you want that image to be deleted from your wordpress at all, you have to use media library to do so.

Comment: How would I go ahead and remove the mapping?

Comment: if you are using default theme like 2012, it has option button named "Remove header image"

Comment: That doesn't remove the mapping, only sets back the default header image. I'll update my question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have found your answer.
I had a similar issue, in that I had unwanted header images in my header image 'gallery' and wanted to chose 'random images' as my header. This of course meant that my unwanted headers would also show up.
I went to my server and deleted the image source directly, but still the image tried to load in the **Appearance > Header** section. I then went to **Media > Library** and found the deleted files still appearing in my library (with 'header' appended to the name). I deleted the files from my Media Library and that removed then from my header page options as well. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you upload the image to media first, and then designate the image in the WP theme customization (header section), it creates a duplicate of the image in the MEDIA section. Before saving the image, I add "HEADER" to the image name so that I can differentiate the two images. That way, when I need to swap out easily, I can simply delete the image with "HEADER" in the title but still retain the original image for when I need to designate it as a header/banner in the future. Hope that helps!